# Database Connected, but no data found

Tags: php, mysql

I have created this page, I have put dummy content into MySQL database, I have ran the same query in phpMyAdmin and it brings back data, yet on the web page it is bringing up "No Data".

Have I missed something? (obviously blanked out database details)

```
<?php

// Connection Info
$host ='localhost';
$user ='-----';
$pass ='-----';
$dbname ='-----';

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);

if($conn->connection_errno){

    echo "Connection Failed" . $conn->connect_error;
    exit();
}
?>

<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if($results->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['title'];
    }
    echo"We Have Data";
} else {
    echo"No Data";
}

?>
```

Comment: :) I know why. `sed s/results/result/g` I do have fat fingers sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following line

```
if($results->num_rows > 0){
```

to

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
```

Comment: Wow thanks... how the hell did i not see that :/ ,... cheers bud.

Comment: because sometimes a big issue is a very small thing to fix. Be careful with the opening and closing of ```, `'`, `"`, `any brackets` as finding those in scripts is very fun and time consuming. I heard there are good LINTing tools now available (free) which can tell exactly how you can fix it. but typos are really hard to find. In your case, IF statement helped why it went to `else` section.

Answer (score 0):

He typo mistake friend

Make following changes in to your code

From 
if($results->num_rows > 0){

To

if($result->num_rows > 0){